# Email Download from Mail server and Get Correct Mail Body using C#

Tags: c#, mime, pop3

```
POP3 objPOP3 = new POP3(server.ToString(),Email.ToString(),password.ToString());
objPOP3.Connect();
if (objPOP3.IsAPOPSupported)
{
    objPOP3.SecureLogin();
}
else
{
   objPOP3.Login();
}

objPOP3.QueryServer();
int count = 0;
for (int index = LastDownloadIndex + 1; index <= objPOP3.TotalMailCount; index++)
{
        try
        {
            count = count + 1;
            string filename, name;
            EmailMessage objEmail = objPOP3.GetMessage(index, false);
            DateTime msgtime1 = Convert.ToDateTime(objEmail.Date);
            string msgsubject = objEmail.Subject.ToString();
            string msgbody = objEmail.Body.ToString().Replace("'", "");
```

I am using this coding for downloading mail from mail server , but that time geting email content is like this

```
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--__=_AltPart_342684501_457771220
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Resume For Managing Director Resume For Managing Director Resume For Mana= ging Director Resume For Managing Director
--__=_AltPart_342684501_457771220
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Resume For Managing Director  Resume For Managing Director  Resum= e For Managing Director Resume For Managing Director
--__=_AltPart_342684501_457771220--
```

Comment: Yes, thats MIME encoded content.  To get the decoded content you need a MIME parser, seeing if there is one built into whatever POP3 client your using is the place to start.

Comment: How is possible ? can you explain me

Comment: Read the documentation. Different clients have different methods to do it.